# ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter

Tags: kernel, webdav, fuse

I was just wondering why my davfs2 mount no longer works:

```
root:/media# mount -t davfs https://XXX /media
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
/sbin/mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse failed
/sbin/mount.davfs: waiting for /dev/fuse to be created
/sbin/mount.davfs: can't open fuse device
/sbin/mount.davfs: trying coda kernel file system
/sbin/mount.davfs: no free coda device to mount

root:/media# modprobe fuse
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root:/media# rmmod fuse
rmmod: ERROR: Module fuse is not currently loaded

root:/media# ll /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157K Jan 17 22:29 /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
```

I am not sure what caused this. But I think there might be a problem with my kernel version:

```
root:/media# uname -r
    3.16.0-4-amd64

root:/media# dmesg
    [879073.041349] fuse: Unknown symbol sysfs_create_mount_point (err 0)
    [879073.041947] fuse: Unknown symbol sysfs_remove_mount_point (err 0)

root:/media# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
    ii  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64        3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3         amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
    ii  linux-image-amd64                 3.16+63                       amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)

root:/media# dpkg -l | grep fuse2
    ii  libfuse2:amd64                    2.9.3-15+deb8u2               amd64        Filesystem in Userspace (library)
```

I am running cron-apt, which recently upgraded the kernel and after three days libfuse2 - maybe there was a reboot between it. What I tried:

- reinstalled packages: linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64, libfuse2, dafvs
- update-grub (seemed to be OK)
- update-initramfs -u -k all (seemed to be OK)
- rebooted several times

Maybe this version difference is the problem?

```
root:/ # aptitude show linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 
State: installed 
Version: 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3

root:/ # uname -a 
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone has a suggestion what to do, to solve the problem?
Thank you very - **very** - much.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually never gotten davfs to work. Not sure how well-supported it is anymore.
However, there is a GUI workaround. I use an application called gigolo to mount my dav filesystems in the GUI, and have set it up to automount when I log in.
It's maybe not quite as solid as a permanent davfs mount, but it could get you access to your dav files.